# magento override block function not calling

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I override my sales order view info but the function not working.

**`config.xml`**

```
<global>
<adminhtml>
<rewrite> 
 <sales_order_view_info>MPS_Delivery_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info</sales_order_view_info>
</rewrite>
</adminhtml>
</global>
```

**`info.php`**

```
class MPS_Delivery_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info
{
    public function getMyTest(){

        return "Test";
    }
}
```

I called in my template in this **`<?php echo $this->getMyTest();?>`**

What mistake i made here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have error in your **config.xml**

Your xml structure is not correct.
You need to add your rewrite code in `<block>` tag and not in `<config>` tag.

Try adding below inside your `<config>` tag.

```
<blocks>
    <delivery>
    <class>MPS_Delivery_Block</class>
    </delivery>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <sales_order_view_info>MPS_Delivery_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Info</sales_order_view_info>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

Also the file you have created is in wrong location.
Create your **Info.php** at **app\code\YOUR_CODEPOOL\MPS\Delivery\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\View\Info.php**

Add your code

```
<?php
class MPS_Delivery_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Info extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info
{
    public function getMyTest(){

        return "Test";
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG Thanks Bro... Can you please tell me How to override Sales order shipement page

Comment: Will require more details, please add a new question for your new requirement with description about which block to override.

Answer (score 0):

In config.xml you have to add tag `<blocks>` like:

```
<global><blocks><adminhtml><rewrite>
```

And Info.php file should have to under **Adminhtml** folder like:
Block/ **Adminhtml** /Sales/Order/View/Info.php